# ayuda con consulta entityframework al mostrar relaciones

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hola amigos recurro a ustedes para poder solventar la siguiente duda

tengo dos entidades de nombre MtoProcedimientos y MtoZonas

Mtoprocedimientos tiene la siguiente relación

```
public int MtoProcedimientoId { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<MtoZona> mtoZonas { get; set; }
```

y en la entidad mtozonas tiene la relación

```
public int MtoProcedimientoId { get; set; }
public virtual MtoProcedimiento mtoProcedimiento { get; set; }
```

ahora bien cuando hago una consulta de la siguiente manera.

```
 // GET: Procedimientos/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {            

        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        var mtoProcedimiento = db.MtoProcedimientos.Find(id);


        if (mtoProcedimiento == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(mtoProcedimiento);
    }
```

lo que quiero es obtener la información de las 2 entidades, para hacer un resumen; pero aunque hay registros en la tabla mtozonas que cumplen con las condiciones, no obtengo ningún registro.

adjunto imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

creen que puedan ayudarme, de antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Para que ef te traiga las relaciones o propiedades de navegación deberías configurar le los includes

puedes ver https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 0):

les comento que este problema lo resolví quitando de mi DBContext la siguiente linea.

```
//this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```